# returned data won't output to my textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
                lstNominalAccounts = NominalAccount.FindUserNominalAccounts(
                    basePage.CurrentSageDatabase,
                    searchText, 
                    basePage.CurrentUser.UserID );

                foreach (NominalAccount oNominal in lstNominalAccounts)
                {
                    strBuilder.Append(oNominal.AccountName + " " + oNominal.AccountNumber + " " + oNominal.CostCentre + " " + oNominal.Department + ":");
                }
                 strBuilder = strBuilder.Remove(strBuilder.Length -1,1);

                 return strBuilder.ToString();



//When i hover over the returned strBuilder it shows the record that ive typed in for //autocomplete but it wont output to my textbox(#tbNominalAccounts)


//this is my success statement on my ajax autocomplete if that helps also

success: function (data) {
                        var datafromServer = data.d.split(":");
                        source: datafromServer;
                    },
```

Comment: You have to show more info. Have you checked with fiddler what is transferred over the wire? So you see any javascript errors? Any .NET exceptions?

Comment: there'd no javascript errors! it posts the value thats been typed in the search text but theres no response

Comment: "Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property."

Comment: You should update your question. Anyway i have posted an answer to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you say you get an exception because you are exceeding the value of the `JavascriptSerializer.maxJsonLength` property.

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx) for the docu of that property.

You can change that value in your Web.config, but i would recommend to check wheather its possible to reduce the amount of data you send because `maxJsonLength` defaults to 4MB which is should be large enough for a web app i think:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**

To your second question about 401 - not authorized:

When using pagemethods you have to allow access to the whole page as far as i know.
When your page contains other methods or code that is available to authenticated users, you can move the pagemethod to another page or create an asmx webservice.

You can edit your Web.Config to include a `<location>` tag under `configuration`:

```
<location path="Datenschutz.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: yeah had done that already, but thanks! i have another problem now '401 unauthorised' on post method 'GetUserNominalAccounts' you know how i can allow Anonymous Access?

Comment: Depends on the framework you use. MVC? Webforms? Something else? How do you authorize your users? In which context do you call the code you have shown (MVC action, static pagemethod, webserice)?

Comment: .net framework 3.5 , asp.net webforms, and i'm calling a static page method, not sure how we authorise our users i have not designed our application